# How to cite references in R Markdown from Endnote library (.enl)?

Tags: r, markdown

Any ideas how to cite references in R Markdown from Endnote library (.enl)? This [webpage](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html) says it's possible but I can't get it to work.

If I export the .enl (available [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45856548/Library_short.Data.zip), I zipped the .enl and data folder) into .xml (available [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45856548/Library_short.xml)), it works:

```
---
title: "test"
author: guys
output: pdf_document
bibliography: Library_short.xml
---  

something something dark side... [@Marshall1989]

# References
```

I can also make it work if I convert the library into .bib (available [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45856548/Library_short.bib)):

```
---
title: "test"
author: guys
output: pdf_document
bibliography: Library_short.bib
---

something something dark side... [@RN1]

# References
```

But it's not convenient, because every time I add a ref in Endnote I would have to export the .enl library into xml or bib.
Thanks

Comment: I have the exact same question but cannot find any answer to it. Are there any news on this? Is there a way to "push up" his question?

Comment: old question, but I'm tackling this now and it looks like the citR package allows it : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/citr/index.html

Answer (score 2):

One method that I found, which may or may not be convenient is to simply copy and paste the reference from Endnote onto the R markup where the paranthetical citation would happen, such as {Stevenson, 2014 #566}. When it is compiled as a word document, you can simply click on update citations and bibliography in Word. This works for one-off reports, but I'd find it inconvenient if you are trying to make a number of reports.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if Endnote is not working with Markdown since the identifiers are not allowed to start with a number - but Endnote identifiers are all numbers.
Source: [R Markdown Not Rendering Citation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644665/r-markdown-not-rendering-citation)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to export your reference as a BibTex file. It is going to be downloaded as a txt file, you should change the extension into .bibtex and define the yaml as:

```
bibliography: "nameofthefile".bibtex
```

You can then open the file and search for the keys and insert into your main text. I hope this helps!